# select multiple rows from multiple table

Tags: php, mysql

**table1**

```
 id  | name | can  | some
---- +------+------+-----
1    |A     | can1 | f
2    |B     | can0 | g
3    |C     | can1 | h
4    |d     | can2 | i
```

**table2**

```
id  | name | description
----+------+--------------
1   |can0  | some text
2   |can1  | another text
3   |can2  | text to
```

I have two tables. I **want to get row with** `id=3` from `table1`and get `description` of `can1` from `table2`.

I tried this

```
SELECT t1.* , t2.description 
from table1 as t1 , table2 as t2 
WHERE t1.can = t2.name
```

but this is not work.please help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain id of second table rather than text

table:- T1

```
id  | name | can    | can_id
---- +------+-------+--------
1    |A     | can1  |  2
2    |B     | can0  |  1
3    |C     | can1  |  2
```

Table:- T2

```
id  | name | description
----+------+--------------
1   |can0  | some text
2   |can1  | another text
3   |can2  | text to
```

Query Without maintain ID O table T2

```
select t1.*,t2.* from T1 as t1 join T2 as t2 on t1.can = t2.name
```

With Id

```
select  t1.*,t2.* from T1 as t1 join T2 as t2 on t1.can_id = t2.id
```

Comment: thanks.i use second method "whit id" and work.but first method not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1 .*, table2.description 
from table1
JOIN table2 on table1.can = table2.name
where table1.id =3
```

The best way is to join two tables, and use columns you need from joined table(in this case table2.description)

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what you changed and why.

Comment: If you assign an alias to the table, you have to use the alias, you can't refer to `table1.can` and `table1.id`.

Comment: Oki, my mistake. I copied part of his code, i will edit my answer.. tnx

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put `t1.id = 3` in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT t1.* , t2.description 
from table1 as t1 , table2 as t2 
WHERE t1.can = t2.name AND t1.id = 3
```

However, you should get more modern and use ANSI `JOIN` syntax rather than cross-products, as in Zeljka's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* 
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.can = t2.name
```

Answer (score 0):

learn about [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.description  FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id where t1.id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Inner Join like

```
SELECT table1 .*, table2.description 
from table1
JOIN table2 on table1.can = table2.name
where table1.id =3
```

Or use **Left Join** if Table2 is optional means if you don't have same `table1.can`  and `table2.name` then also you will get all value from `table1` then.
Do like this:

```
SELECT table1 .*, table2.description 
from table1
LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.can = table2.name
where table1.id =3
```